# Can't read integer from file to matrix

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to read from a file an array of numbers with an unknown size and save it as a matrix. The code must be as compact as possible, which is why I don't want to read file as string and then convert it to an int.

```
int main() 
{   
    ifstream infile("array.txt");
    int n, counter = 0, **p;
    while (!infile.eof()) {
        counter++;
    }

    counter = sqrt(counter);
    cout << "counter is " << counter << endl;
    p = new int*[counter];

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        p[i] = new int[counter];

    while (!infile.eof()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
                p[i][j] = n;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
        cout << p[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code, it was made for a square matrix. The problem is, I can't read the file at second time to save the numbers to the matrix.

Comment: Do you even read from the file?

Comment: `while (!infile.eof()) { counter++; }` is an infinite loop.

Comment: 1> infinite loop as suggested above. 2>  your file pointer gets to the end while you try to get counter. so close the in file after while loop. 3> open the file again to save into matrix.

Comment: Why do you use `new` and `[]`. That's more like C code. C++ has better ways, e.g. `vector<vector<int>>`. Anyway, you need to read from the file! I can't see a single line of code that actually reads the file. Google `ifstream`

Comment: @rahul.deshmukhpatil how can i get my pointer again to the begin of the list?

Comment: @StillLearning i never heared about vector<vector<int>>

Comment: @bg_mi - Then you should start read about the standard containers of C++. They'll save you a lot of trouble. BTW - how is the input format? A single integer per line?

Comment: @StillLearning no, i generated a random matrix 5x5 and saved it in to the file, now i`m trying to read the same matrix from file

Comment: @bg_mi - And how is it saved? 5 integers per line? 25 lines with one integer each? One line with 25 integers? Separated by space? You need to explain such stuff - if you don't no one can help...

Comment: @StillLearning 5 integers per line

Comment: @bg_mi Then it seems you have a complete solution in the answer below.

Comment: @bg_mi : close and re-open file, it will set to beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of problems in your code. A big one is that you have several infinite loops and aren't even reading from a file. An even bigger problem is that you're not using C++ constructs. I've written a small program that does what you're trying to do using more C++ concepts. In this case, you should use a `std::vector` - they will handle all the dynamic sizing for you.

## test.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// Nobody wants to write `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` more than once 
using int_matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

void populate_matrix(int_matrix& mat, const std::string& line) {
  int num;
  std::stringstream ss(line);
  std::vector<int> row;
  // Push ints parsed from `line` while they still exist
  while(ss >> num) {
    row.push_back(num);
  }
  // Push the row into the matrix
  mat.push_back(row);
}

// This is self-explanatory, I hope
void print_matrix(const int_matrix& mat) {
  size_t n = mat.at(0).size(); 
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      std::cout << mat.at(i).at(j) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int_matrix mat;

  // Pass the file as a command-line arg. Then you don't need to worry about the path as much.
  if(argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Number of arguments is wrong\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // Open file with RAII  
  std::ifstream fin(argv[1]);

  std::string line;
  // Handle each line while we can still read them
  while(std::getline(fin, line)) {
    populate_matrix(mat, line);
  }
  
  print_matrix(mat);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code assumes the text file looks something like this:

## numbers.txt

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

i.e., `n` lines with `n` numbers per line separated by whitespace.

To compile and run this code, you can follow these steps:

```
13:37 $ g++ test.cc -std=c++14
13:37 $ ./a.out /path/to/numbers.txt
```

Comment: If there's anything that's confusing, please ask and I can explain more.

Comment: sorry for such stupid question, but i don`t understand, where should i write the name of the file. I am a beginner, have never seen code like this

Comment: That's not a stupid question. When you have an executable, you can execute it with the filename as a parameter. If you compile this code into `./a.out`, you would run it with `./a.out numbers.txt`

Comment: and if i`m using windows at the moment?

Comment: I don't know how Windows works, but you can look for command-line arguments for MSVS.

Comment: Just one quibble: `return -1;` should be `return EXIT_FAILURE;` for portability. (`return 0;` is okay; it's the same as `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`)

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the tip; I'll change it. :)

Comment: @erip hi, dude, you helped me some time ago, can you please give me an ansver on one simple question. I decided to install Linux on my PC. Can you advise me some linux distribution, which you prefer?

Comment: @bg_mi I like OpenSUSE.

Comment: @bg_mi Also, if this answer helped you, don't forget to check the "accepted" answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the program runs once through the file and later you run another while loop to read from the file. When you read from a file, then its like your "cursor" moves forward. So basicly, if you hit the end, you have to reset the cursor back to the start of the file. 
You can set your cursor back with seekg(0).(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/)

Comment: Oh i just really saw, that endless counter, sorry my bad.